# Squid via Haproxy

Tags: squid, haproxy

Anyone experienced with configuring Squid to forward requests to HAproxy?
I use Squid as a proxy, with ACLs and other stuff, and I need to know if I can tell it to forward requests to HAproxy, which would act as a load balancer that **is aware** when one of the backends is down.

Comment: O_o And what's the problem?

Comment: How would you implement an source-IP ACL? All the connections would seem to come from haproxy. Or does Squid have the ability to look at a particular request header instead? (I'm considering doing similar things with a different load-balancer product).

Comment: I guess the really dumb solution is to put another layer of Squid in front of Haproxy. Sorry but this is a really old topic, and whatever experience I had back then with Squid, has long been forgotten :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using squid for caching shouldn't you be using WCCP and a WCCP capable router instead ? That allows you to load balance connections and can detect when a node is offline.

Comment: I do not have access to any router. I can only implement linux-based solutions, that's why I need to find a way so that when a node has no internet access, the other working node is chosen by Squid. And I was thinking at HAproxy for this.

Answer (score 0):

HAProxy can perform health checks using the "httpchk" option.

```
backend mybackend
    option httpchk HEAD /check.txt HTTP/1.0
    server server1 123.123.123.101:80 check
    server server2 123.123.123.102:80 check
    server server3 123.123.123.103:80 check
```

HAProxy will look for /check.txt on each target node, and take it out of the cluster automatically if it doesn't receive an HTTP 200 on that file.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to use [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/releases/varnish-cache-3.0.2) which can reverse proxy, cache, and do http checks of available back ends. Your Squid/HAProxy solution would work, but can be hard to troubleshoot when tcp sessions are going through multiple daemons.